# What is the standard comparator when using sets in c++

Tags: c++

I thought is would be the memory address of the respective object, but for pointers it's apparently the object address to which they point. That's why I'm a bit uncertain...

Comment: The default comparator for `std::set` is simply `std::less`, which uses `operator <` underneath. Are you asking how `operator <` is defined for different types?

Comment: It's `std:less`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wouldn't that be a breaking change? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) doesn't mention it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I just checked the standard. I was wrong. I was reading about a change in `std::sort` where the default is specified as `std::less{}` since C++20 and I got confused and thought the same was done in `set`...

Comment: It's `std::less` which, for pointers compares then using an expression of the form `first < second`.     That gives undefined behaviour if the objects those pointers point at are unrelated (e.g. not in the same data `struct`, not elements of the same array, etc).

Comment: @Peter yes, but in this case I have two pointers pointing to the same objects, so the set looks at the objects address instead of the pointer address?

Comment: @Jacob please post a [mcve] to save us asking you lots of "what are you doing" types of questions ?

Comment: @Peter No, unlike `<`, `less` never causes this kind of UB. It provides a strict weak order even for unrelated pointers.

Comment: @Peter why then do I only have one object in my set when I add the two pointers?

Comment: Please ask a new question for this different problem. Include a [mcve] in that question.

Answer (score 3):

Just looking up [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) will tell you that it is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)

```cpp
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

The behaviour is same for pointer types as well. It will simply compare the addresses. You could try copying the same object in two different addresses. The set would store both the pointers.